# Replace occurences in a String

Tags: java, string, replace, substring, indexof

How can i replace the occurences of a given String but without the first occurence and last occurence?
The inputs are taken from keyboard.
Examples :

```
INPUT: "a creature is a small part of a big world"
        a
        the
OUTPUT: "a creature is the small part of a big world"
```

Another example:

```
INPUT: "a creature is a small part"
       a
       the
OUTPUT: "a creature is a small part"
```

In the last one the String remains the same because both the occurences(i.e character 'a') are first and last.

Comment: Are familiar with Regular Expressions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Otherwise, find the first from the beginning and the first from the end, replace everything in between.

Comment: @user871611 I have tried to find the indexes of each occurence, but i've failed.

Comment: @pm77-1 This is what I've already tried, but how do you find the last element?

Comment: Straight replace of `" a "` with `" the "`.(Notice spaces)

Comment: @pm 77-1 This won't work(See the second example).

Comment: In the second example it will replace nothing. Write the code, add it to your post, and explain the actual difficulty.

Comment: What about a in small (sm"a"ll) and part(p"a"rt)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.replaceFirst(String, String)`:

```java
String a = "a creature is a small part of a big world";
String b = "a";
String c = "the";
String d = a.replaceFirst(" " + b + " ", " " + c + " ");
System.out.println(d);
```

... prints out:

```
a creature is the small part of a big world
```

Read the documentation for more information:
[String documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

---

Edit:

Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Here is an example for replacing all occurrences except the first and last one:

```java
String a = "a creature is a small part of a big world";
String b = "a";
String c = "the";

String[] array = a.split(" ");
ArrayList<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].equals(b)) {
        occurrences.add(i);
    }
}

if (occurrences.size() > 0) {
    occurrences.remove(0);
}
if (occurrences.size() > 0) {
    occurrences.remove(occurrences.size() - 1);
}
for (int occurrence : occurrences) {
    array[occurrence] = c;
}

a = String.join(" ", array);
System.out.println(a);
```

---

Edit:

With an alternative type for the occurrences collection:

```java
String a = "a creature is a small part of a big world";
String b = "a";
String c = "the";

String[] array = a.split(" ");
Deque<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayDeque<>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].equals(b)) {
        occurrences.add(i);
    }
}

occurrences.pollFirst();
occurrences.pollLast();

for (int occurrence : occurrences) {
    array[occurrence] = c;
}

String d = String.join(" ", array);
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Better use Deque and  targetIndexes.pollFirst();  targetIndexes.pollLast(); so you won't have to check size and mess with index.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.functional;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class StringReplacementDemo {

    public static void appendString(String str){
        System.out.print(" "+str);
    }
    /**
     * @param str1
     * @param output2 
     * @param input 
     */
    public static void replaceStringExceptFistAndLastOccerance(String str1, String input, String output2) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str1.split(" "));
        int index = list.indexOf(input);
        int last = list.lastIndexOf(input);
        UnaryOperator<String> operator = t -> {
            if (t.equals(input)) {
                return output2;
            }
            return t;
        };
        list.replaceAll(operator);
        list.set(index, input);
        list.set(last, input);

        list.forEach(MainClass::appendString);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = "a creature is a small part";
        String input = "a";
        String output ="the";
        replaceStringExceptFistAndLastOccerance(str1,input,output);
    }
}
```